# Autowired ApplicationContext has not method getBean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest, spring-ioc

I have autowired ApplicationContext in my RestController class as I needed to create a prototyped bean for each of the request received.

To create the bean I tried context.getBean(xx) but context has not getBean() method listed. Is there a way that I can get beans of the prototyped class in my RestController class. I am running this application as Spring boot.

sample code is here:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/Restcompare")
public class CompareService {


    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private Comparator comparator;

    @RequestMapping("/compare")
    public String vcompare(@RequestParam(value="pre", defaultValue="") 
    String pre, @RequestParam(value="post", defaultValue="") String post){


        comparator = context.getBean(Comparator.class);  //Error here
    }
}
```

**Update:**

***Solution:*** Somehow IDE imported a different ApplicationContext other than the Spring framework's. Correcting the import to `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` resolved the issue.

Comment: Which IDE are/were you using? Just curious.

Comment: Spring Tool Suite!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow IDE imported a different ApplicationContext other than the Spring framework's. Correcting the import to org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject your bean with `@Autowired`, like this:

```
@Autowired
private Comparator comparator;
```

Comment: This won't work as the  comparator bean in compareService class is created only once.  The correct way is to create prototyped bean using context only. The problem I had is spring imported a different ApplicationContext other than spring's. Correcting the import to org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext resolved the issue. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Oh, no problem!